# Is "weight of a sand bucket" analog or digital in nature?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, design

I've got Digital Logic Design course this semester, during the introduction of this course my professor emphasized about the difference between digital and analog devices, and then gave us some examples from things around us, two of these examples confused me:

1. Grains of sand in a bucket is digital
2. weight of a sand bucket is analog.

What I was thinking is that it's pretty much the opposite!

Can I have some explanation to this?
[image: book]

Comment: I think you're wrong with the "opposite", but I'd still say it's a terrible example. Point is that you can *count* grains of sand, but you can't *count* weight. But *countable* doesn't imply *digital*, so I really don't agree in any way with the example (but I'm absolutely certain that you're wrong – *physical weight* is not a digital quantity; but neither is *count of grains of sand* per se.)

Comment: I agree that it is a terrible example, but maybe he meant that you can't have "half" a grain of sand, while with weight you can have infinite decimal places? 10.00012312.. kg?

Comment: @MarcusMüller reference book states that: Generally, anything that can be expressed as "the number of.." is digital. Does that make sense? I've included a snap of some examples.

Comment: the point is that the text above talks about *digital **quantities***, whereas I was assuming your prof was talking about *digital **signals***.

Comment: In any case, we already have a word for what the text means and it's *continuous* and *discrete*. At least where I come from it's not common to talk of *quantities* as digital or analog; we can find a *digital representation* of a *discrete quantity*, giving us *digital data*.

Comment: Yes, I find these types of questions very confusing, they can be answered from different point of views.

Comment: What @WesleyLee suggested sounds reasonable for me, thank you!

Comment: @WesleyLee he, nice example. So, that's physically actually proper, but it demands a high degree of insight in solid state physics, right? In what we would "classically" expect, since atoms have fixed masses, and energy states in which these can be and combine to sand crystals, we would have to assume that the mass of the sand is a *rational number*. We can *count* the rational numbers, just like we can count the natural numbers. Rational numbers are hence part of the discrete world – and so would be the weight of the sand :) If "countable" is the criterion, then "weight of …

Comment: @WesleyLee … sand in classic physics" is digital, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Like I said, I agree that it is a bad example. That was just my interpretation of it after trying to make some sense of it, not saying that that analogy will hold to any scrutiny at all. :)

Comment: It depends on if you quantize such weight or not. If you somehow record the weight without quantizing it, e.g by casting a piece of metal of exact same weight and keep it as a record, then it's not digital, but no analog, either, because you don't have a continuous record but a series of samples. Another example of such "discrete time" signal is air samples: if you sample air into a container at certain times and preserve them, then the series of air samples forms a discrete time signal. However if quantize the composition and write them on paper, the quantization process makes it digital.

Comment: bucket is bad example. number of bricks in wall is digital. number of jenga cubes in a box is digital. vibrations in a jenga stack is analogue.

Comment: "Analong" and "digital" are the wrong words to use.  The number of grains of sand in a bucket is a _discrete_ quantity, while the weight is a _continuous_ quantity.  Analog and digital are two different modes of _signal processing_.  In analog signal processing, we use a continuous quantity (e.g., voltage, current) to represent some measurement while in digital signal processing, we convert measurements to a stream of numbers and process them with computing machinery.  You can use either kind of representation (analog or digital) for either kind of measurement (discrete or continuous.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question whether something is digital or analog is actually *hard*. The point that the text you're citing makes is that anything that can be represented as a count of discrete entities is digital.

In that sense, since grains of salt are countable, the count is a "digital quanitity". Since you can't count "weights", the weight isn't digital.

I don't agree with that wording, personally. I've not come across the term "digital quantity", and frankly, we already have a term for that – it's called *discrete*, and all definitions that surround the term *digital* revolve around the concept of discreteness. So, calling a quantity *digital* feels like a circular definition:

- "Hey, what's a digital datum?"
- "It's something that represents a digital quantity."
- "So what's a digital quantity?"
- "Something representable by digital data."

As you notice, meh, that's not a definition.

Instead, we usually restrict the usage of the word "digital" to three use cases:

1. Digital signals (vs. analog signals)
2. Digital electronics
3. Digital data

## Digital signals

I'm working a lot with signals, so I have a favourite definition of this. Note that for something to be called digital signal, you need to have a *mathematical signal model* first. No model, no digital-ness!

> A signal is digital if, and only if, it only exists for discrete loci and can only take one of a discrete set of values.

With *locus*, most often we mean *time*, but it might also be the position in an image, for example.

*Discrete* is the core concept here. We call sets *discrete sets* if they are *countable*, such as the Natural Numbers (1, 2, 3…), and all the sets that we can bijectively map to these (or a subset) – be it the Alphabet (a,b,c…), be it more abstract things like \$\mathbb Q\$ (yes, the rational numbers are countable. That's why the "weight of something" example is dangerous. The real numbers are not countable.)

## Digital Electronics

Electronics that work with discrete steps – for example,  the input of a flip flop is either high or low, never "anything in between. The circuitry works in a manner where it's only relevant in which of the discrete voltages, currents, frequencies … that are provisioned by the circuit's design the input falls, not its continuous value. (E.g., your flip flop doesn't care whether your input voltage is 0.0 V or 0.00001123288… V, if the threshold between high and low is 0.5 V)

## Digital Data

This is a term that comes from information theory.

You have to ask yourself: Is something capable of transporting *infinite information* or not; if it's not capable, then whatever it is might be represented by digital data.

For example, dice might only show one of six sides showing up – we can very easily see that to represent the state of the die, we only need a finite amount of bits (less than three, actually).

On the other hand, when you spin a wheel and it has no "steps", and you just stop it at any angle in \$(0, 2\pi(\$, then the info "we hit exactly this angle" is not representable by any finite amount of bits, if you can just look closely enough.

Digital Data is hence a representation of something with finite information content – or its a lossy representation of something that used to contain a higher amount of information before it underwent *digitization*.

## Coming back to your sand

Forget about "digital quantities". Think about quantities either being *discrete* (i.e. only taking values from a discrete set of values) or *continuous* (i.e. you can't just go ahead and count through all the values).

The set of possible numbers of grain in a bucket is discrete – it's a subset of \$\mathbf N\$, the natural numbers. The number of grains is a *discrete quantity*.

When you count the number of grains in that bucket once per week, you get a *digital signal*; it exists once per week, and it can only take discrete values.

When you build a digital scale to weigh the sand, what really happens is that some sensor measures the pressure on a special structure and converts it to a current, that an amplifier amplifies. If you where to understand that current as a function over time, you'd notice that it looks something like \$f:\, \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R\$, i.e. the *continuous quantity* (locus) time is mapped the *continuous quantity* current. That is an *analog signal*. Then, to be digital, your scale would need an analog to digital converter, that, for example, would measure whether the current is below \$a\$ mA, below \$2a\$ mA, below \$3a\$ mA, \$4a\$ … \$1000a\$ mA. The highest step that it is still above would be the *quantized* value. Since that converter is only sampling for discrete times, it converts an analog to a digital signal – it is an Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC). From there on, *digital circuitry* processes the signal, converts it to other digital signals used to control the display on the scale. In contrast, the amplifier directly after the pressure sensor is not digital circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the examples given are easy. According to the book, anything that is enumerable (can be represented with integers), is digital and anything that can have fractional values is analog.
Not sure if one can classify a quantity as analog or digital. The classification actually depend on how the data is represented. Try to understand the examples:

Grains of sand in a bucket when plotted on a number scale will take only discrete values (integers). And these discrete values can be represented exactly using binary numbers. Now this is a digital representation of that quantity.

Weight of a sand bucket can take any value on the number scale. When you represent the value as such, say 19/3 kilograms, it is analog representation of that weight. If you want to represent analog values using binary numbers with complete precision, you will need infinite number of bits.

One can round-off this number to nearest discrete level and represent using binary numbers. Then the data becomes digital. For example, the number 19/3 can be represented as 110 in 3-bit binary number. The corresponding value is 6 kilograms but the original value was 6.33333... kilograms. The precision can be improved by using more number of bits.